# Unable to run a hello world app in Tizen

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm unable to run a simple  native application "hello world" in tizen 2.4 rev2 due to an error shown in the screenshot.

I'm trying to run it on a real device which is setup for development -- 
Developer Options are visible and Debug via USD is activated.

How to fix it?

[image]

UPDATE1:

Right click on the id of a device -> Permit Install applications and an error:

[image]

How can I register it? Is it that all only to run a simple hello world application?

UPDATE2:

[image]

UPDATE3:

I've generated a certificate, but there's no "*.crt" file, there's only p12. What should I do in this window?

[image]

Comment: Right click device_id (It's some long random number) on device list. Click "Allow apps installation to this device". It will load your signature on the device and you are good to go...

Comment: @VikramDattu, updated my question.

Comment: check if it installs fine on emulator. You MUST do certificate registration if you want to install app on real Tizen device. The registration is free and simple to do. Here is link : https://developer.tizen.org/fr/development/tools/common-tools/certificate-registration?langredirect=1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if it installs fine on emulator. Because emulator don't need certificate registration.
You **MUST** do certificate registration if you want to install app on real Tizen device. The registration is free and simple to do. Here is link : https://developer.tizen.org/fr/development/tools/common-tools/certificate-registration?langredirect=1 .

Do this again : `Right click on the id of a device -> Permit Install applications`. It uploads certificate to that device.

Look into this link about registration : http://developer.samsung.com/gear/guide-registering-certificates

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE** :
*Question demands info about .crt file :*

Follow the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please note the .csr file path. You will need it.

[image]

Do login.

[image]

Upload .csr file.

After doing these steps, you will get e-mail with .crt file.
[image: email snapshot containing author.crt attachment]

Upload .crt file with password,

[image: Upload .crt file with password]

Same goes for device profile.

[image: Request Device profile]

[image: Request test profile]

This time you will receive .xml file with **password** [Don't forget to use this password for "Device profile" section].[image: email sanapshot containing device-profile.xml file]

Upload .xml file you received via email, and password you received via e-mail.

[image: Upload .xml]

Right click on device from connection explorer and > permit to install applications...

[image: Connection explorer]

And finally you will see this beautiful screen... :)

[image: Succeeded to upload certificate.]

Now try running app. It should run fine :) :) :)

Comment: where should I do "certificate signing request"?

Comment: @AlanCoromano, the image you uploaded, In "Author" tab, there is one Clickable named "Generate a certifiacate signing request". Click on that, it will take you to the page where you can generate a certificate. Then do "Request the certificate", then you will get mail with author.crt file.

Comment: the last error is still the same "Cannot install application.

Error code: FATAL_ERROR
Error message: 
Command: /usr/bin/pkgcmd -q -i -t tpk -p "/opt/usr/apps/tmp/org.example.basicdaliapplication3-1.0.0-arm.tpk"
Management: Installation or uninstallation is not working temporarily."

Comment: I've uploaded the certificate and compiled the app successfully, but when I ran it, I got the error.

Comment: the error I posted above. **"Cannot install application. Error code: FATAL_ERROR Error message: Command: /usr/bin/pkgcmd -q -i -t tpk -p "/opt/usr/apps/tmp/org.example.basicdaliapplication3-1.0.0-arm.tpk" Management: Installation or uninstallation is not working temporarily."**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102696/discussion-between-vikram-dattu-and-alan-coromano).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the target system time is invalid.
You can adjust the system time with setting application.
When the application is installed, the target time will be checked.
It's for checking the certificates validation.
The error message is not kind to find the proper reason, It will be improved in near future.

Comment: the time on my computer and phone are in the same time-zone.

Comment: so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need an extra plugin for retail device ?

What is your actual device ? I assume it works on emulator...