# How can I generate registration certification for gear s2?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

When I tried to generate the registration certification, I made the author certification, but when I submitted the project it has been rejected because of a certification issue.

Does anyone know how can I complete the registration successfully?

And what file should I upload?

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried. Provide us with a minimal, complete and verifiable example [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Goto `Tizen IDE`
2. Goto `Help` Menu
3. Select `Help Contents`
4. Page web page in your browser will open.
5. In the left pane you have `Certificate Guide` node.
6. Read it out and follow the steps given in this section.

Answer (score 0):

All the process for generating certificate for Gear S2 are described in the below link:
http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/getting-certificates

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have given step wise answer for registration procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35148151/3249583). :
If you follow the steps properly, it's simple and straight forward.
Hope this helps.